# What is (are) scenerios and practical settings that can possibly lead to the weibull-log-Logistic mixture distribution?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, censoring, weibull-distribution, finite-mixture-model, logistic-distribution

In my paper I studied Weibull-loglogistic mixture distributions in reliability and life testing, some structural properties of the model are presented including moments, reliability, hazard rate function, and maximum likelihood estimate of the unknown parameters.
journal reviewer's comments are :
"What is (are) typical scenarios and practical settings that can possibly lead to the Weibull-logistic mixture distribution? The authors did not clearly present or articulate the possible importance and potential practical situations as well as real life cases or aspects leading to such an endeavor.

" The question seems to be complicated, i don't understand it or what i must do to answer it ."

All suggestions are welcomed
Thank you in advence

Answer (score 1):

The danger with more complicated models is: "With four parameters I can fit an elephant, and with five I can make him wiggle his trunk," as [John von Neumann](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) put it. So I I think that it's reasonable to expect some explanation of what practical advantages a more complex model like the log-logistic Weibull model (4 parameters to fit by my quick look) could provide. See the paper that evidently developed that model: [Oluyede et al, Austrian Journal of Statistics 45: 43-69, 2016](https://doi.org/10.17713/ajs.v45i3.107).

Although the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) has wide use in failure-rate analysis it only allows for monotonic changes in the event hazard over time. Some failure rates (like human survival from infancy to old age) have more of a [bathtub shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve) over time: high to start, decreasing to a stable rate for a while, then rising at late times. According to Oluyede et al, the log-logistic model allows for such shapes. (I have only skimmed the paper, so can't verify.) The authors also provide a few examples.

Comment: Thank you so much .
Your answer is very useful